# Visual C Runtime 2005 version download

Tags: download, version, crt, visual-c++-2005

I am having one EXE, which is executing on one m/c but not in other, both are having Windows 7.

When I try to execute it, it throw below errror message,

"The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail."

As I suggested, I used SXSTrace.exe and found problem is with C-RT,

```
ERROR: Cannot resolve reference Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.5592".
```

The m/c where its executing, required file's are present at,

```
c:\windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_d09154e044272b9a\MSVCM80.DLL
```

As you know we can't copy inside "winsxs" folder.

Since, I required "Visual C-Runtime version 8 (2005) x86 v 8.0.50727.5592 or 8.0.50727.6195.

Required library files of older versions are present in System:

```
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_d08d7da0442a985d\msvcm80.dll
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.42_none_db5f52fb98cb24ad\msvcm80.dll
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_d08cc06a442b34fc\msvcm80.dll
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_none_10b2f55f9bffb8f8\msvcm80.dll
```

I would like to know if I required same library of different version which will be installed inside "winsxs" folder then which installer I required

Can you please pinpoint the url from where I can get this software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the link mentioned below.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcmfcatl/thread/c1dc12ae-f032-4c20-9ff9-c16ea531ca08?prof=required

Thanks,
Amit